# Custom customer attributes erase when updating email or password

Tags: magento, magento2

I've created custom customer attributes for internal usage, I mean, that are only available for the admin on Backend. The issue is that, if the user updates its email or password from its account those custom attributes erase... Literally  empty. By the other hand, If I modify the email or the password for a user from the Backend those fields remain intact, I mean, the info is not erased.

This is how I've created the attributes:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0){ 

            //Numero de Cliente
           $eavSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
                'numcte',
                [
                    'label' => 'Numero de Cliente',
                    'system' => 0,
                    'position' => 100,
                    'sort_order' =>100,
                    'visible' =>  true,
                    'note' => '',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'input' => 'text',

                ]
            );
            $numcte = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'numcte');
            $numcte->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout']);
            $numcte->save();

        }




    }

}
```

I can see the attributes on Backend and actually I work with those values in some other processes. But here I'm literally crazy on what is going on. I've been the las 2 days trying to figured out what's going on. Could you help please?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace the below code:

```
$numcte->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout']);
```

With this one:

```
$numcte->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer']);
```

And then try to create the attribute. For re-create please first remove the module entry from the setup_module table and then run the upgrade command.

Comment: Dude! It works like a charm!. I just delete the attribures, not the entry from the setup_module.  Thankyou!

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem was solved. Please accept answer.